# How to require subtypes of an abstract class to implement a static instantiator?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, static-methods

```
public abstract class A
{
    // constructors omitted

    public abstract A Create(SomeData data);
}

public class B : A
{
    // constructors omitted

    public override A Create(SomeData data)
    {
        return new B(data);
    }
}
```

What I want is to be able to make the `Create` method static, so that I can get an instance of B without having to create a useless instance with an empty constructor. (If you're wondering why, A is actually a generic type of the form `A<TFoo, TBar>`, where `TBar` corresponds to the derived types. As we all know, you can't instantiate a generic type using a constructor that takes any arguments.)

I am already aware that static methods are decoupled from the object hierarchy, only relying on the name of the type. That means I can't have `Create` as an abstract method that I force all descendants to implement. Is there another way I can implement this pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is simply no way to do this.  Inheritance is based off of instance methods in C# and has no equivalent feature for static methods. Another way to implement this pattern though is to require a lambda in lieu of a static method.

For example (you mentioned the actual type was `A<TFoo, TBar>`)

```
void UseIt<TFoo, TBar>(A<TFoo, TBar> p, Func<SomeData, TBar> func) {
  TBar b = func();  
  ...
}
```

The consumer doesn't care if `Create` is static, instance or even called create.  Generally all they care about is having a function which takes a `SomeData` and returns a `TBar`.  Delegates fit this pattern exactly.

Comment: My actual use case is creating instances of the derived type in methods that are implemented in the abstract base class. For example, every type `TBar` derived from `A` should have a `Clone` method that is implemented exactly the same way: instantiate a new `TBar` with some data stored in a field. I was hoping to be able to pull off something like `TBar.Create(_MyData)`. This `Clone` method might have to be invoked within `A`, so naturally I can't pass it a lambda that instantiates `TBar`. I'm sorry if I'm being unclear, please bear with me.

Comment: @Asad why can't you pass a lambda exactly?  In any situation where a static method would work a lambda would also be available.  It may be simply that you need to pass the lambda into the constructor of `A<TFoo, TBar>` to make this happen though

Comment: Yes, it works if the lambda is passed in externally. Within the body of `A` though, `TBar` is a type parameter, and can't be instantiated with arguments (through a lambda or otherwise). I guess I could add a parameter for the lambda to the constructor for `A` and store it in a field, although this means I have to pass in a lambda that instantiates the right derived type every time I want to instantiate an `A`.

Comment: @Asad that is essentially the solution I was proposing.

Comment: I understand, I was just thinking out loud.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might work, depends on your requirements

```
public abstract class A
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public static T Create<T>(string data) where T : A, new()
    {
        return new T() { Data = data };
    }
}

public class B : A { }
```

then can do

```
A foo = A.Create<B>("foo");
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but `Data` is modeled as read only (all derived types of A are supposed to be immutable). Is there a way to get around this without making `Data` settable?